Supremum of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck (O-U) process
Suppose $X(t)$ is a zero-mean Ornstein-Uhlenbeck (O-U) process and let $a<b<c$ be positive real numbers. I am wondering if $\sup_{0 < t < a
\, \text{or}\, b < t < c}X(t)$ has the same distribution as $\sup_{0 < t < a+c-b}X(t)$, and, if not, whether there is any stochastic domination between them (using perhaps Slepian's lemma). I know I have to use stationarity and the Markov property, but I'm getting stuck on the details.

Let $X(t)$ be a centred Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process where we note that its covariance is given by
$$\text{Cov}((X(s), X(t)) = \frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}e^{-\theta|t-s|}, \ \ \forall s,t.$$
Define $L = a + c - b$, which we will use as a way to map the union of $[0, a]$ and $[b, c]$ into a single contiguous interval. Further define the following two processes:
$$Y(t) = \begin{cases} X(t), & \text{for } t \in [0, a], \\ X(t + b - a), & \text{for } t \in [a, L]. \end{cases}
$$
which for $t \in [0, a]$ represents the OU process on the first interval and for $t \in [a, L]$, the same process on the shifted second interval $[b, c]$, as well as
$$Z(t) = X(t), \ \ \text{for} \ \ t \in [0, L]$$
It is easy to see that
$$\sup_{t \in [0, a] \cup [b, c]} X(t) = \sup_{t \in [0, L]} Y(t)  \ \ \ \ \text{and}   \sup_{t \in [0, a+c-b]} X(t) = \sup_{t \in [0, L]} Z(t)$$
As OU processes are GPs, we attempt to apply Slepian's Lemma to $Y(t)$ and $Z(t)$. The first condition of the lemma is that the processes have zero mean which in this case they inherit from $X(t)$.  Secondly, we check that
$$\text{Var}\left[ Y(t) \right] = \text{Var}\left[ Z(t) \right] = \frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}$$
for all $t \in [0, L]$ which again holds true as $X(t)$ has constant variance given by the above. Finally we have to check that for all $s, t \in [0, L]$ it holds that
$$\text{Cov}(Y(s), Y(t)) \le Cov(Z(s), Z(t))$$
We consider 4 cases.
Case 1 - $s, t \in [0, a]$:
$$\text{Cov}(Y(s), Y(t)) = \text{Cov}(X(s), X(t)) = \text{Cov}(Z(s), Z(t))$$
Case 2 - $s, t \in [a, L]$:
$$\text{Cov}(Y(s), Y(t)) = \text{Cov}(X(s + b - a), X(t + b - a)) =  \text{Cov}(Z(s + b - a), Z(t + b - a)) =  \text{Cov}(Z(s), Z(t))$$
Case 3 - $s \in [0, a], t \in [a, L]$. Here we have the following covariances for $Y$ and $Z$
$$\text{Cov}(Y(s), Y(t)) = \text{Cov}(X(s), X(t+b-a)) = \frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta} e^{-\theta |t+b-a-s|}$$
$$\text{Cov}(Z(s), Z(t)) = \frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}e^{-\theta|t-s|}$$
Since $b \ge a$, $|t+b-a-s| \ge |t-s|$ so $e^{-\theta |t+b-a-s|} \le e^{-\theta |t-s|}$ and so $\text{Cov}(Y(s), Y(t)) \le \text{Cov}(Z(s), Z(t))$
Case 4 - $s \in [a, L], t \in [0, a]$: Symmetrical with case 3.
Having checked all three conditions, we apply Slepian's Lemma and obtain that
$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \in [0, L]} Y(t) \ge v \right) \le \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \in [0, L]} Z(t) \ge v \right), \ \ \forall v \in \mathbb{R} \iff \\
\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \in [0, a] \cup [b, c]} X(t) \ge v \right) \le \mathbb{P} \left(   \sup_{t \in [0, a+c-b]} X(t) \ge v \right), \ \ \forall v \in \mathbb{R}$$
So $\sup_{t \in [0, a+c-b]} X(t) $ stochastically dominates $\sup_{t \in [0, a] \cup [b, c]} X(t)$.

Thank you for the elegant answer! I wonder if the stochastic domination is also true for the absolute value process $|X(t)|$.

$|X(t)|$ is no longer a GP so the above construction certainly wound't apply. There are some results that deal with the expected supremum of the absolute value GP, but mostly as measures of boundedness as far as I know.
